# How to control image zooming while scrolling the page in Doughnut Chart using achartengine in android?

Tags: android, achartengine, donut-chart

I created Doughnut Chart using achartengine for my application. This is my output.I created this page with scroll View. This is my half of my page.

[image]

When i scroll my page its became like this.

[image]

My code is here http://pastie.org/8696613. I gave these controls to avoid zooming and moving.

```
   renderer2.setPanEnabled(false);
   renderer2.setZoomEnabled(false);
```

But i don't know why my chart re-sized when I am scrolling my page? Anybody can help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this  problem you have to edit library code .

In `GraphicalView.java`, Method `onDraw` at the beginning

```
canvas.getClipBounds(mRect);
int top = mRect.top;
int left = mRect.left;
int width = mRect.width();
int height = mRect.height();
```

to

```
int top = 0;
int left = 0;
int width = getMeasuredWidth();
int height = getMeasuredHeight();
```

Copied from https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=31

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this behavior, I suggest you do:

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```